# Adding Dropdown Option to a Pure CSS Content Filter

Tags: html, css, dropdownbox

I'm trying to add a dropdown option to this pure CSS filter that does the same action as clicking the radio buttons as seen here in the original codepen: http://codepen.io/allienworks/pen/vOGMzV

This dropdown would be used for mobile, while the radio buttons would be for medium+.

I've tried a few different options to get this going, including trying basically all related selectors, adding

```
select[name="dropdown"] option[value="red"]
```

to the code, rearranging, getting rid of the radio buttons, and a few others but nothing seems to budge. You can see what I landed with, which seems like it should work, here: http://codepen.io/budgetdumpster/pen/rVQbLV

So I guess my question is if there is a way to have this option in pure css? I'm not afraid of using JS or Jquery as a last resort but wanted to keep with the pure css theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to pure CSS.  Just put the `label`s in a container and proceed to style them the way you would like.  You can use media queries to style the container into a dropdown for smaller devices.  [This article by Scott O'Hara](http://www.sitepoint.com/content-switching-component-built-three-ways/) is excellent at showing how to use this CSS trickery.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background:#f5f5f5;
}
h1 {
  text-align:center;
}
.container {
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
#blue:checked + label {
  background:#6666ff;
}
#blue:checked ~ .tile:not(.blue) {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}
#red:checked + label {
  background:#ff4466;
}
#red:checked ~ .tile:not(.red) {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}
#green:checked + label {
  background:#66dd99;
}
#green:checked ~ .tile:not(.green) {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}

.tile {
  width:23%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  transition:all 1s;
  margin:0.5%;
  padding:0.5%;
}
.green {
  background:#66dd99;
}
.blue {
  background:#6666ff;
}
.red {
  background:#ff4466;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.dropdown label {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown label:not(.default) {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .default,
.dropdown:focus .default {
    color: lightgray;
}

.dropdown:hover label:not(.default),
.dropdown:focus label:not(.default)
 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>FILTER BY COLOR</h1>
<div class="container"> 
  <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" />
  <input type="radio" id="red" name="color"/>
  <input type="radio" id="green" name="color"/>
  <input type="radio" id="reset" name="color"/>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <label class="default">Select your option</label>
  <label for="green">GREEN</label>
  <label for="red">RED</label>
  <label for="blue">BLUE</label>
  <label for="reset">RESET</label>
    </div>

  <div class="tile blue">1</div>
  <div class="tile red">2</div>
  <div class="tile blue">3</div>
  <div class="tile green">4</div>
  <div class="tile blue">5</div>
  <div class="tile red">6</div>
  <div class="tile red">7</div>
  <div class="tile green">8</div>
  <div class="tile blue">9</div>
  <div class="tile green">10</div>
  <div class="tile red">11</div>
  <div class="tile green">12</div>
  <div class="tile blue">13</div>
  <div class="tile blue">14</div>
  <div class="tile green">15</div>
  <div class="tile red">16</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @BDDev No problem! Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there essentially buttons that are validating the value that are set to them. For the drop down you do that but the inputs set the value. So keep the input select but add a button that passes the value to either red or blue or green.

Either that or you can use something like:

```
<input type="text" value="somevalue" onBlur="return validate();">
```

onBlur you will have to build a validate function with JavaScript that will pass the info for the value.

That's one method. Others might be able to come up with something less noobish than my ideas :P